# Ruby on Rails - Problems with DELETE and EDIT of an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently i am struggling with creating my first rails web app. It should be a blog (following the tutorial).
I can create new articles, see them but somehow my DELETE and EDIT buttons are not working (showing error messages). I searched hours for solutions (here & on other forums) but couldnt figure it out so i am kindly asking for help from you guys! (thanks in advance!).
Versions: Rails(4.0.0), Ruby(2.3.3p222)... LEt me know if you need anything more that is not stated here.

**Controller file**

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  include EventsHelper

def index
  @events = Event.all
end

def show
   @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end

def new
   @event = Event.new

end


def create
   @event = Event.new(event_params)
   @event.save

   redirect_to event_path(@event)
end

def destroy
   @event = Event.find(params[:id])
   @event.destroy
   redirect_to events_path
end

def edit
   @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end

def update
   @event = Event.find(params[:id])
   @event.update(event_params)

   redirect_to event_path(@event)
end

private
def event_params
   params.require(:event).permit(:title, :body)
end
end
```

**show.html.erb** (where i call EDIT & DELETE)

```
<h1><%= @event.title %></h1>
<p><%= @event.body %></p>
<%= link_to "<< Back to Event List", events_path %>

<p> </p>
<br>

<%= link_to "edit", edit_event_path(@event) %>
<%= link_to "delete", event_path(@event), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<h1>Edit an Event</h1>

<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <ul>
<% @event.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
<li><%= error %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<p>
<%= f.label :title %><br />
<%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :body %><br />
<%= f.text_area :body %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Events::Application.routes.draw do
   root to: 'events#index'
   resources :events
end
```

**Output of routes:**

```
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
      root GET    /                          events#index
    events GET    /events(.:format)          events#index
           POST   /events(.:format)          events#create
 new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)      events#new
edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format) events#edit
     event GET    /events/:id(.:format)      events#show
           PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)      events#update
           PUT    /events/:id(.:format)      events#update
           DELETE /events/:id(.:format)      events#destroy
```

**Error Messages:**

> After EDIT ->  Couldn't find Event with id=edit
>
> After DELETE -> No route matches [DELETE] "/events"

**event.rb** (in this location -> events/app/models)

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
end
```

`**20170513124425_create_events** (migration file of event)

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
       t.string :title
       t.text :body

       t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In your show view why do you have both an `@events` and an `@event` variable... typo?

Comment: Because when i tried to use `@event` in the first 2 lines, i got this error message -> `NoMethodError in Events#show -> undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass`  ... Maybe do you have a suggestion how to fix that problem pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just recreated your app. There were a few things I had to do to get it to work. First, make sure you run rake db:migrate.

1. In your index action, change `@event` to `@events`.

The reason for this is you are trying to show all events on the index page, not just a single event.

2. In your destroy action, change your redirect_to call to `redirect_to events_path`.

Currently, when you delete an event, you are trying to redirect back to that event. Since the event no longer exists, you are getting an error.

3. In your show.html.erb file, change both occurrences of `@events` to `@event`.

You are going to show only one event on this page, not all events.

4. Change the first line of your routes.rb file to `Rails.application.routes.draw do`

If you make these changes, your app should work. You should also put your event_params method in a private section in your controller.

Comment: I made all the changes and still not working :-/. Now when i click on the event i get this error message `NoMethodError in Events#show -> undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass`  ... Any other suggestion please? I even put my private `event_params method` at the end of the controler

Comment: replace `@events` with `@event` in your `show` view

Comment: Yes, got it! But what should i do with that? It just shows all the instances in the Event table. (every event has a title)

Comment: I am still getting the error `undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass` after i changed from @events to @event in the show.html.erb .. Can create the event (when i go on events/new) but can not see the detail of it. After clicking on the event i get the error mentioned in the beginning of the post.

Comment: [TUTORIAL LINK](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i1:-form-based-workflow) This one i just changed the name from article to event, name of the project from blogger to events & i am not using the partial forms.

Comment: @hashrocket MAN you did it! It helped and now both EDIT & DELETE functions are working. Thumbs up for your work& time. Please put an answer here to maybe help people in the future. It started to work after writing `rake db:migrate`